# SQL join or R's merge() function in NumPy?

Tags: python, sql, numpy

Is there an implementation where I can join two arrays based on their keys? Speaking of which, is the canonical way to store keys in one of the NumPy columns (NumPy doesn't have an 'id' or 'rownames' attribute)?

Comment: Related: [NumPy equivalent of merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495344/numpy-equivalent-of-merge)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to use only numpy, you can use **structured arrays** and the `lib.recfunctions.join_by` function (see http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.lib.recfunctions.html). A little example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn
   ...: a = np.array([(1, 10.), (2, 20.), (3, 30.)], dtype=[('id', int), ('A', float)])
   ...: b = np.array([(2, 200.), (3, 300.), (4, 400.)], dtype=[('id', int), ('B', float)])

In [2]: rfn.join_by('id', a, b, jointype='inner', usemask=False)
Out[2]: 
array([(2, 20.0, 200.0), (3, 30.0, 300.0)], 
      dtype=[('id', '<i4'), ('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8')])
```

Another option is to use **pandas** ([documentation](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/index.html)). I have no experience with it, but it provides more powerful data structures and functionality than standard numpy, "to make working with “relational” or “labeled” data both easy and intuitive". And it certainly has joining and merging functions (for example see http://pandas.sourceforge.net/merging.html#joining-on-a-key).

Answer (score 1):

If you have any duplicates in the joined key fields, you should use `pandas.merge` instead of `recfunctions`. Per the docs (as mentioned by #joris, http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.lib.recfunctions.html):

> Neither `r1` nor `r2` should have any duplicates along `key`: the presence of duplicates will make the output quite unreliable. Note that duplicates are not looked for by the algorithm.

In my case, I absolutely want duplicate keys. I'm comparing the rows of each column with the rows of all the other columns, inclusive (or, thinking like a database person, I want an *inner join* without an *on* or *where* clause).  Or, translated into a loop, something like this:

```
for i in a:
  for j in a:
    print(i, j, i*j)
```

Such procedures are frequent in data mining operations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).