# Adding column to numpy array based on where condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and I would like to update a column of values in it with data from a second array. Somewhat like a vlookup function in excel.

Need to look-up the first column of `a` in the `b` table. Then replace the second column in `a` with the number from the second column in `b`.

```
import numpy as np

# type, newval
a = np.array( [[1, 23, 0],
              [2, 24, 0],
              [1, 15, 0],
              [1, 27, 0],
              [6, 22, 0],
              [1, 18, 0]]
              )

# type, newval
b = np.array([[1, 1.1],
            [2, 2.1],
            [3, 3.1],
            [4, 4.1],
            [5, 5.1],
            [6, 6.1]]
            )

a[:,2] = np.where(b[:,0] == a[:,0], b[:,1], None)
```

**Expected result**
**Note:** I would like the original array `a` to be updated with the lookup values.

```
a = array( [[1, 23, 1.1],
            [2, 24, 2.1],
            [1, 15, 1.1],
            [1, 27, 1.1],
            [6, 22, 6.1],
            [1, 18, 1.1]]
          )
```

What I get however is `nan` beside the last 4 items in the array. It likes like my `np.where` condition is replacing the value where the position AND the number are correct, not just where the number matches.

Comment: Note, the `b` array can be a list or any other type of object if it makes things easier. The `a` array is read in from a file so I'd prefer not to change the structure of that.

Comment: Are you sure that your "Expected result" is correct? In the second row, second column i would expect a 2.1.  Rows 5 and 6 seems to be interchanged.

Comment: Zinjaai, yep you're correct. I've fixed it above. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join or R's merge() function in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776907/sql-join-or-rs-merge-function-in-numpy)

Answer (score 3):

You can transorm the array `b` into a dictionary.
Afterwards the desired result can be archived by list comprehension.

```
b_as_dict = dict(b)
res = [[k, b_as_dict[k]] for k in a[:,0]]
```

---

Regarding inserting these results into `a`:

Currently `a` is an integer array. To get these results into `a` you'll probably want to define it as `float` or `float32` (because the values you're trying to insert are floats):

```
a = np.array([[1, 23, 0],
          [2, 24, 0],
          [1, 15, 0],
          [1, 27, 0],
          [6, 22, 0],
          [1, 18, 0]],
         dtype=np.float32)
```

Then you can use list comprehensions as Zinjaai suggested:

```
a[:, 2] = [b_as_dict[k] for k in a[:, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way to get these results into the original array? Thing is, I have more columns in `a` than displayed in the example I gave above.

Answer (score 1):

If b is sorted and consecutive, the simples solution is:

```
In [19]: b[a[:,0]-1]
Out[19]: 
array([[ 1. ,  1.1],
       [ 2. ,  2.1],
       [ 1. ,  1.1],
       [ 1. ,  1.1],
       [ 6. ,  6.1],
       [ 1. ,  1.1]])
```

Or, a bit slower:

```
In [20]: a[:,0]
Out[20]: array([1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1])
```

By subtraction 1, these are the indices of our array `b`

```
In [21]: a[:,0]-1
Out[21]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0])
```

Now we just read these rows from `b`.

Comment: I like this solution too. If the lookup table `b` can be sorted in this way it is probably faster.