# Numpy simple join 2 arrays

Tags: python, numpy, join

How can I join two numpy arrays together, based on common values in each first column, or zero if no match? The arrays need not be the same length. The first column in each array represents a unique ID, and the second column is the count, both obtained from np.unique. The ultimate goal is to simply subtract the counts of each unique ID.

```
a = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4]])
b = np.array([[1,10],
              [2,20],
              [3,30]])
```

Desired output:

```
c = np.array([[1,10,2],
              [2,20,0],
              [3,30,4]])
```

Comment: Can you please explain some more how array `c` is obtained from `a` and `b`? Your description about common values is not clear to me.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join or R's merge() function in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776907/sql-join-or-rs-merge-function-in-numpy)

Comment: I suppose that works, although it seems like something that should be possible using only vanilla numpy functions/slicing, rather than either recfunctions or pandas.

Comment: As can be seen in `recfunctions.join_by` code, there are lots of choices to deal with - the type of join, dealing with missing values, etc.  A plain vanilla numpy function with the same generality would be just as fiddly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all consecutive rows in b are present:

```
z = np.zeros((b.shape[0],1),dtype=int)
c = np.hstack((b,z))
ai = a[:, 0] - 1
c[ai,2] = a[:, 1]
print c
```

A more general solution, if both a and b have missing rows:

```
d = np.union1d(a[:, 0],b[:, 0]).reshape(-1,1)
z = np.zeros((d.shape[0],2),dtype=int)
c = np.hstack((d,z))
mask = np.in1d(c[:, 0], b[:, 0])
c[mask,1] = b[:, 1]
mask = np.in1d(c[:, 0], a[:, 0])
c[mask,2] = a[:, 1]
print c
```

Comment: Thanks, this is quite instructional for me, particularly the boolean masking syntax (e.g. c[mask,1]). I'm just really surprised there is no numpy "join this to that" functionality, as in pandas.