# NumPy equivalent of merge

Tags: python, numpy, merge

I'm transitioning some stuff from R to Python and am curious about merging efficiently. I've found some stuff on `concatenate` in NumPy (using NumPy for operations, so I'd like to stick with it), but it doesn't work as expected.

Take two datasets

```
d1 = np.array([['1a2', '0'], ['2dd', '0'], ['z83', '1'], ['fz3', '0']])
```

```
ID      Label
1a2     0
2dd     0
z83     1
fz3     0
```

and

```
d2 = np.array([['1a2', '33.3', '22.2'], 
               ['43m', '66.6', '66.6'], 
               ['z83', '12.2', '22.1']])
```

```
ID     val1   val2
1a2    33.3   22.2
43m    66.6   66.6
z83    12.2   22.1
```

I want to merge these together so that the result is

```
d3

ID    Label    val1    val2
1a2   0        33.3    22.2
z83   1        12.2    22.1
```

So it's identified rows that match on the ID column and then concatenated these together.  This is relatively simple in R using `merge`, but in NumPy it's less obvious to me.

Is there a way to do this natively in NumPy that I am missing?

Comment: See: [SQL join or R's merge() function in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776907/sql-join-or-rs-merge-function-in-numpy/7778713)

Comment: Are you strictly limited to `numpy`?  Most people use `pandas` to match functionality from R.  e.g. [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: I am not opposed to using pandas, however I believed swapping between pandas and numpy (since I plan to use numpy for operations later on) will be inefficient. I could be wrong here, though.

Comment: I'll +1 the Pandas suggestion. Pandas DataFrames are built on top of NumPy arrays. Pandas is best for operations like the one described in your question, and you can access the underlying Numpy array of a Pandas DataFrame `df` any time using `df.values`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join or R's merge() function in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776907/sql-join-or-rs-merge-function-in-numpy)

Answer (score 6):

Here's one NumPy based solution using masking -

```
def numpy_merge_bycol0(d1, d2):
    # Mask of matches in d1 against d2
    d1mask = np.isin(d1[:,0], d2[:,0])

    # Mask of matches in d2 against d1
    d2mask = np.isin(d2[:,0], d1[:,0])

    # Mask respective arrays and concatenate for final o/p
    return np.c_[d1[d1mask], d2[d2mask,1:]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: d1
Out[43]: 
array([['1a2', '0'],
       ['2dd', '0'],
       ['z83', '1'],
       ['fz3', '0']], dtype='|S3')

In [44]: d2
Out[44]: 
array([['1a2', '33.3', '22.2'],
       ['43m', '66.6', '66.6'],
       ['z83', '12.2', '22.1']], dtype='|S4')

In [45]: numpy_merge_bycol0(d1, d2)
Out[45]: 
array([['1a2', '0', '33.3', '22.2'],
       ['z83', '1', '12.2', '22.1']], dtype='|S4')
```

We could also use `broadcasting` to get the indices and then integer-indexing in place of masking, like so -

```
idx = np.argwhere(d1[:,0,None] == d2[:,0])
out = np.c_[d1[idx[:,0]], d2[idx[:,0,1:]
```