# How to merge 2 numpy ndarray on a ndarray using values of a column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, numpy-ndarray

I have 2 ndarray:

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [5,0], [6,4]])
b = np.array([[1,10],[6,30], [5,20]])
```

I wish merge them in a array as this:

```
[[ 1  2 10]
 [ 5  0 20]
 [ 6  4 30]]
```

Someone knows a not iterative mode to merge 2 array by values of column 0?

I've found only this way:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2], [5,0], [6,4]])
b = np.array([[1,10],[6,30], [5,20]])
new0col = np.zeros((a.shape[0],1), dtype=int)
a = np.append(a, new0col, axis=1)
l1 = a[:,0].tolist()
l2 = b[:,0].tolist()
for i in l2:
    a[l1.index(i),2] = b[l2.index(i),1]
print(a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join or R's merge() function in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776907/sql-join-or-rs-merge-function-in-numpy)

Comment: Also: [NumPy equivalent of merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495344/numpy-equivalent-of-merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
c = np.c_[a, b[np.searchsorted(a[:, 0], b[:, 0]), 1]]

print(c)

array([[ 1,  2, 10],
       [ 5,  0, 20],
       [ 6,  4, 30]])
```

Breaking this down, note the row indexing applied to `b` retrieves the indices of `a[:, 0]` for each value in `b[:, 0]`:

```
print(np.searchsorted(a[:, 0], b[:, 0]))

[0 2 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative solution with **pandas**, is less effcient than **numpy**, but I wish post it too, because i think that is instructive.
The good solution that give to me [jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9209546/jpp) (I did not know that method), has a limit, *a* and *b* must have same keys.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def merge_w_np(a, b):
    zeros = np.zeros((a.shape[0], np.shape(b)[1] -1), dtype=int)
    a = np.append(a, zeros, axis=1)
    l1 = a[:,0].tolist()
    for j, i in enumerate(b[:,0].tolist()):
        a[l1.index(i),2] = b[j,1]
    print(a)

def merge_w_pd(a, b):
    dfa = pd.DataFrame(data=a,                      # values
                       index=a[:,0])                # 1st column as index
    dfb = pd.DataFrame(data=b,                      # values
                       index=b[:,0])                # 1st column as index
    dfa.columns = ['id', 'value']
    dfb.columns = ['id', 'value']
    # print('a',dfa)
    # print('b',dfb)
    dfc = dfa.merge(dfb, left_on='id', right_on='id', how='outer')
    print(dfc)

a = np.array([[1,2], [2,8], [5,0], [6,4], [7,9]])
b = np.array([[1,10],[6,30], [5,20]])
merge_w_np(a, b)
merge_w_pd(a, b)
```