# How to compare elements in two numpy-arrays and add other element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy arrays with differents lenghts(~ 25k), look like:

```
a = [['0110000TPK019906K' '325096'] ['0110000TPK01PR12' '225091']...]

b = [['0110000TPK019906K' '4']['0110000TPK01TGTX12K' '5']...]
```

I need to find all similar elements a[i][0] and b[i][0] and add b[i][1] in array a. Result should be like:

```
a = [['0110000TPK019906K' '325096' '4']
```

So I wrote this code and I have some question?

```
i = 0    
while ( ): # which condition I should use?
        if a[0][i] == b[0][i]:
                quantity = b[0][1]
                np.append(a[0], b[i][1])
        else:
            # how go to next element in array b?
```

Or, maybe, more effective way exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join or R's merge() function in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776907/sql-join-or-rs-merge-function-in-numpy)

Comment: Also: [NumPy equivalent of merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495344/numpy-equivalent-of-merge)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list-comprehension`.

```
new_array = np.array([[i[0],i[1],j[1]] for i,j in zip(a,b) if i[0]==j[0]])

print(new_array)
```

Output:

```
[['0110000TPK019906K' '325096' '4']]
```

Comment: Well,  it works, but I see only a few elements instead 14k that how supposed to be. Because if i[0]!=j[0]  then program do nothing. I trying to write like this a = np.asarray(list_all_stock)
b = np.asarray(list_art) 
i = 0
j = 0
all = zip_longest(a,b)
for i,j in all:
    if i[0]==j[0]:
        np.array([[i[0], i[1], j[1]]])
    else:
        np.array([[i[0], i[1], 0]]) but i have TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable