# Making Loop-Finding Faster: Numpy Equivalent of Pandas Merge?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, duplicates, graph-theory

I start with a list of parent/child (edge) relationships in a directed graph, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['parent', 'child'])
df.loc[0] = (0, 1)
df.loc[1] = (1, 2)
df.loc[2] = (2, 0)
```

You can see right away that we have the loop `0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 0`. I want to be able to detect these loops in a dataframe such as I have. My strategy so far (which works but is too slow on my much larger dataset) is to utilize the pandas merge function:

```
def find_loops(link_df: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    link_df.columns = ['0', '1']
    # Max number of iterations - don't expect to need this many.
    num_appts = len(set(link_df['0']) | set(link_df['1']))
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(link_df)
    for i in range(num_appts):
        new_df = new_df.merge(link_df, left_on=str(i+1), right_on='0', how='inner')
        new_df.drop(columns='0_y', inplace=True)
        new_df.columns = [str(j) for j in range(i+3)]
```

This gives me, at each loop iteration, the array in `new_df.values` containing paths of increasing length (`i+3`). If a path ends and has no loops, then the `merge` function automatically drops that row, which is very nice. To detect a loop, I look for duplicated values along a row of `new_df.values` like so:

```
        paths = new_df.values.astype(np.int32)
        is_loop = pd.Series(paths[:, 0] == paths[:, 1])
        width = i + 3
        for j in range(width - 1):
            for k in range(j+1, width):
                is_loop = is_loop | (paths[:, j] == paths[:, k])

find_loops(df)
```

I need this code to run a lot faster. Any ideas? One idea I had was to try to do the pandas `merge` function in numpy, but I have no idea which function would even come close to being able to do that.

I have already tried the `duplicated` function, the `Counter` object, and the `np.unique` function, none of which were remotely as fast as what I have here.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495344/numpy-equivalent-of-merge), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776907/sql-join-or-rs-merge-function-in-numpy/7778713); are some of these functions the way to go?

Comment: What you probably want is to use networkx, in particular https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html

Comment: @DaniMesejo Very nice! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['parent', 'child'])
df.loc[0] = (0, 1)
df.loc[1] = (1, 2)
df.loc[2] = (2, 0)


dg = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent', target='child', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
res = list(nx.simple_cycles(dg))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1, 2]]
```

From the documentation on [simple_cycles](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html):

> Find simple cycles (elementary circuits) of a directed graph.
>
> A simple cycle, or elementary circuit, is a closed path where no node
> appears twice. Two elementary circuits are distinct if they are not
> cyclic permutations of each other.

In the documentation link above there are some links to additional algorithms that may be of interest.

Comment: I think this is going to work, but I need to make my overall structure more efficient, such as creating the DiGraph only once, and adding or deleting edges from it, instead of re-creating the entire thing each time. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: My loop rate is a tad slower than before I implemented loop-finding, as you might expect, but this solution, in conjunction with the things I mentioned above, is an acceptable speed. Many thanks!